# Chart js aligning multiple charts one on top of the other

Tags: chart.js

I have few charts, one on top of the other. 
It needs to be aligned regardless of Y scale's label width.
Setting padding increased distance starting from the labels, not from the chart.
Is it possible to set width of Y axis labels or something like that?
[image]

Comment: Are you using stacked axes?

Comment: @user2057925 no

Comment: If all charts have got the same x axis, you could try to use the stacked axes. In this way you could be sure that all bars datassets will be shown at the same way. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/stacked.html

Comment: @user2057925 thank you, but unfortunately it should be 3 different charts

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for solution

```
scales: {
  y: {
    afterFit(scale) {
      scale.width = 90;
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: I think that's not enough to be 100% sure about the bar alignement. YOu should also have the same axis config (i.e. count, maxTicksLimit, fonts)