# How to align multiple Charts with Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I created multiple charts with chart.js below each other. I want the grids to be aligned left and right, for easy comparison of the x axis. Because of `LongCategoryName` the charts are not aligned.
[Example of not aligned grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiT7m.png)
I don't know prior to the chart creation which categories I have within a chart. Is there a way to achieve this?
Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/T4rik/bos8w7y0/2/).

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76046627/chart-js-aligning-multiple-charts-one-on-top-of-the-other) suggesting:

```
afterFit(scale) {
  scale.width = 90;
},
```

But for me it just aligns the right side of the scale, I need both sides aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you need to apply the `afterFit` method to the `y2` axes.

```js
y2: {
  type: "category",
  labels: [],
  offset: true,
  position: 'left',
  stack: 'demo',
  stackweight: 1,
  grid: {
    drawOnAreaChart: false
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Dataset"
  },
  afterFit(scale) {
    scale.width = 90;
  }
}
```

[Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn5rad6x/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, after experimenting a bit in my original diagrams I finally got it to work!